# Why aren't the lists populating in this code?

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I wrote this code for class and cannot figure out why my lists are not populating with any values. I've tried using a debugger and still can't figure out why it won't work. Any ideas? Also... I know for loops would have made more sense, but I needed to use while loops for the assignment.

```
__author__ = 'Ethan'
#This program reads in a file from the user which contains lines of

def mileage():
    filename = input("Please enter the file name: ")
    file = open(filename,"r")
    line_list = []
    num_lines = sum(1 for line in file)
    line_counter = 0

    while line_counter <= num_lines:
        line = file.readline()
        line_items = line.split()
        line_list.append(line_items)
        line_counter += 1

    current_index_pos = 0

    while current_index_pos <= num_lines:
        current_item = line_list[current_index_pos]
        print("Leg",current_index_pos + 1,"---", current_item[0]/current_item[1],"miles/gallon")
        current_index_pos += 1
mileage()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This reads to the end of the file

```
num_lines = sum(1 for line in file)
```

so there are no lines left to read when you get here

```
    line = file.readline()
```

Better to structure the code like this

```
with open(filename, "r") as fin:
    for line_counter, line in enumerate(fin):
        line_items = line.split()
        line_list.append(line_items)
    # after the loop line_counter has counted the lines
```

or even (if you don't need line_counter)

```
with open(filename, "r") as fin:
    line_list = [line.split() for line in fin]
```

More advanced would be to use a generator expression or do everything in a single loop to avoid needing to read the whole file into memory at once

```
def mileage():
    filename = input("Please enter the file name: ")

    with open(filename, "r") as fin:
        for line_counter, line in enumerate(fin):
            current_item = line.split()
            print("Leg",line_counter + 1,"---", float(current_item[0])/float(current_item[1]),"miles/gallon")
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. So once you go through a file you can't read it again? I guess I don't understand that part. I'm new to programming so I'm still grasping some of these concepts. Thanks!

Comment: @Efie, the file object keeps track of the position in the file. You can reset it to the beginning (or anywere else in the file) using the seek method. I don't think it's necessary here though